# how can insert li by jquery

Tags: jquery, html-lists, addition

in wordpress menu create

```
<a href="#">menu 1</a>
<a href="#">menu 2</a>
<a href="#">menu 3</a>
<a href="#">menu 4</a>
<a href="#">menu 5</a>
```

but i want to add those are inside li. like this

```
<li><a href="#">menu 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#">menu 2</a></li>
<li><a href="#">menu 3</a></li>
<li><a href="#">menu 4</a></li>
<li><a href="#">menu 5</a></li>
```

i know its possible by jquery . i tried but i can't make it. i am not so pro on jquery so would you help for me.

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest the following:

```
var list = $('<ul />').insertBefore($('a').first());

$('a').each(
    function(){
        $(this).wrap('<li />').closest('li').appendTo(list);
    });​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/WY92f/).

Based on my reading of the comments from the OP (below this answer), the problem of the above not working is likely due to the lack of the code being wrapped in a `$(document).ready()` handler, if that's the case then I'd suggest the following adaptation:

```
$(document).ready(
    function(){
    var list = $('<ul />').insertBefore($('a').first());

    $('a').each(
        function(){
            $(this).wrap('<li />').closest('li').appendTo(list);
        });​
    });
```

Comment: thanks.. i tried ul create in ok but li create after all a .. bellow here created code
<code>
<ul>
<a href="#">menu 1</a>
<a href="#">menu 2</a>
<a href="#">menu 3</a>
<a href="#">menu 4</a>
<a href="#">menu 5</a>
</ul>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
</code>

Comment: Yes; did you try the *edited* answer, as it is currently? Because I changed the code when I realised that `wrap()` returns the original element, not the element with which it was wrapped in the method.

Comment: if i use <script>

var list = $('<ul />').insertBefore($('a').first());

$('a').each(
    function(){
        $(this).wrap('<li />').appendTo(list);
    });

</script>

 to before </head> then li not create and if user that before </body> then li create but not same like before. not in <a>

Comment: <div class="flink">

<a href="#">menu 1</a>
<a href="#">menu 2</a>
<a href="#">menu 3</a>
<a href="#">menu 4</a>
<a href="#">menu 5</a>

</div>

<script>

var list = $('<ul />').insertBefore($('a').first());

$('a').each(
    function(){
        $(this).wrap('<li />').appendTo(list);
    });

</script>

Comment: <pre><code>generate code

<div class="flink">
<ul>
<a href="#">menu 1</a>
<a href="#">menu 2</a>
<a href="#">menu 3</a>
<a href="#">menu 4</a>
<a href="#">menu 5</a>
</ul>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
</div>
<script>
var list = $('<ul />').insertBefore($('a').first());
$('a').each(
function(){
$(this).wrap('<li />').appendTo(list);
});
</script>

Comment: Add your code to the *question*, along with an explanation of what you *did*, and what the problem *is*; adding it in the comments makes it unreadable.

Comment: @david.. i tried but none code is work i trid <blink>text</blink> and <pre><code>text</pre></code>  but not work :(

Answer (score 0):

Add classes to the elements you want to put into `li` elements:

```
<a href="#" class="li_a">menu 1</a>
<a href="#" class="li_a">menu 2</a>
<a href="#" class="li_a">menu 3</a>
<a href="#" class="li_a">menu 4</a>
<a href="#" class="li_a">menu 5</a>
```

Then grab those elements and go through them:

```
var ul = $("<ul></ul>").appendTo("body");
$("a.li_a").each(function() {
    $(this).wrap("<li></li>").parent().appendTo(ul);
});
```

Comment: it's work but in my wordpress i can't really add any class inside a my code is like this
<pre><code> <?php 
$menuParameters = array(
  'menu'            => 'New', 
  'container'       => false,
  'container_class' => 'footmenu',
  'echo'            => false,
  'items_wrap'      => '%3$s',
  'depth'           => 0,
);

echo strip_tags(wp_nav_menu( $menuParameters ), '<a>' );
?>

Comment: @AccoreLTD - Ah, well that's only necessary if you only want to do this for some `a` elements. If you need to do this to all of them, you can skip adding the classes and change `$("a.li_a")` to `$("a")`.

Comment: @jeff.. yes it work.. but have one problem. in my have many ul li etc.. so i want to do this only one div.. say like div class flink. i want to apply this thing only there. now after apply your code take <a> from body and under li on ul